# Debug Flutter stuck on spash screen when built

Tags: ios, debugging, flutter, freeze

I'm working on a Flutter application. It happened to me more than once (this time, when I add `flutter_markdown` to the project) that my app works when I run `flutter run` but when I `flutter build` and use that for opening the app on my phone, the app gets stuck on the splash screen.

I don't have a traditional iOS app development background, so in these cases, it's very difficult for me to figure out the source of the issues.

I tried Xcode clean, clean build folder, `flutter clean`, `rm -rf ~/.pub-cache`, `rm -rf /Users/username/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/Runner-*`, none of this helped, so it looks like there is an actual problem with my app and not some caching issue.

How am I supposed to debug this issue?

Comment: If you build en debug on an actual device (ios) or in the simulator?

Comment: I use a real device (and for some plugins to work that's a requirement)

Comment: ```flutter clean``` then ```flutter build ios --release``` and then in xcode run it?

Comment: Yes, I tried mutliple things, I have the same issue everywhere. I tried building with `flutter clean && flutter build ios --release` and in Xcode (clean then command+B to build. Then I tried installing both through TestFlight and in Xcode Window > Devices and Simulators and then install)

Comment: And it's running on Android?

Comment: Yes, it's running on Android. The thing is that I installed multiple Flutter plugins (with different iOS and Android implementations in the background) and some of them must be breaking my app. The interesting part is that when I run `flutter run` it works, but when I build it, it hangs.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode, open Devices and Simulators (in the Window panel or `Shift+Command+2`).

Here, you'll see your connected devices.

For debugging what causes your Flutter app to hang on the white splash screen, you can either click on the "View Device Logs" or the "Open console" buttons.

In "View Device Logs", you can see the crashes that occurred on that device. If it's empty, then open your app, see it crash and check again.

In "Open console", you see all logs "real time", so this can also help you debug why your app is unresponsive once built.

Don't forget to select the device that's running the app.

As Flutter developers don't always have experience on both platforms, I want to document it anyway here, in case someone needs it (even if it might be obvious for many).